# How can I install rpi.gpio for my Raspberry Pi project and resolve 'python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully' error?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm doing a project to my colege that I need to control some GPIOs pin on my Raspberry. But I couldn't install the rpi.gpio library in my raspberry and im my project inside vscode. Every time tha I writ the comand at vscode's prompt an erro message is wroten:
`× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.`
Note: I'm using `pip install rpi.gpio` trying to install it.
In the RPi when I run the code the terminal shows other erro messages saing that the comand import was not found
`./owncode2.py: line 1: import: command not found ./owncode2.py: line 2: import: command not found ./owncode2.py: line 3: import: command not found`
Is this occuring because I did not add the libraries the right way??

I need some help to resolve this and let my project run.

Comment: Do you have a sheband line in your Python script? Add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line so that the OS knows how to run your script. The error looks like it's treating it as a shell script. Or run it with `python your-script.py` instead.